# brownian.bridge slow calculation and Error in area.grid[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate some BBMM.contours for caribou during a movement period in northern Canada. 
I am still in the exploratory phase of using this function, and have worked through some tutorials which worked fine, but now that I am trying my sample data the brownian.bridge function seems to be taking an eternity.
I understand that this is a function that can take a long time to calculate, but I have tried subsetting my data to including fewer and fewer locations, simply to see if the end product is what I want before committing to running the dataset with thousands of locations. Currently I only have 34 locations in the subset, and I have waited over night for it to run without any completion. 
When I used some practice Panther location data with 1000 locations it took under a minute to run, so I am thinking there is something wrong with my code or my data. 
Any help working through this would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Load data
data<-(X2017loc)

#Used to sort data in code below for all caribou
data$DT <- as.POSIXct(data$TimeStamp, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#Sort Data
data <- data[order(data$SAMPLED_ANIMAL_ID, data$DT),]

#TIME DIFF NECESSARY IN BBMM CODE
###Joel is not sure about this part...Timelag is maybe time until GPS  upload???.
timediff <- diff(data$DT)
data <- data[-1,] 
data$timelag <-as.numeric(abs(timediff))

#set Timelag
data <- data[-1,] #Remove first record with wrong timelag
data$SAMPLED_ANIMAL_ID <- factor(data$SAMPLED_ANIMAL_ID)

data<-data[!is.na(data$timelag), ]

data$LONGITUDE<-as.numeric(data$LONGITUDE)
data$LATITUDE<-as.numeric(data$LATITUDE)

BBMM = brownian.bridge(x=data$LONGITUDE, y=data$LATITUDE, time.lag=data$timelag, location.error=6, cell.size=30)
bbmm.summary(BBMM)
```

Additional information:
Timelag is in seconds and
Collars have 6m location error

I am not certain what the cell.size refers to and how I should determine this number.

> ```
> SAMPLED_ANIMAL_ID   LONGITUDE   LATITUDE    TimeStamp   timelag 
> 218 -143.3138219    68.2468358  2017-05-01 02:00    18000 
> 218 -143.1637592    68.2687447  2017-05-01 07:00    18000 
> 218 -143.0699697    68.3082906  2017-05-01 12:00    18000 
> 218 -142.8352869    68.3182258  2017-05-01 17:00    18000 
> 218 -142.7707111    68.2892111  2017-05-01 22:00    18000 
> 218 -142.5362769    68.3394269  2017-05-02 03:00    18000 
> 218 -142.4734997    68.3459528  2017-05-02 08:00    18000 
> 218 -142.3682272    68.3801822  2017-05-02 13:00    18000 
> 218 -142.2198042    68.4023253  2017-05-02 18:00    18000 
> 218 -142.0235464    68.3968672  2017-05-02 23:00    18000
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have answered my original question, in that I was missing the following code to reproject the latlong to UTM.

```
data <- SpatialPoints(data[ , c("LONGITUDE","LATITUDE")], proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))
data <- spTransform(data, CRS("+proj=utm +west+zone=7 +ellps=WGS84"))
```

Comment: If you have another question, [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question instead of posting half of an answer as a new question. SO is not a forum, and each question is expected to have its own topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use cell.size = 100 instead of area.grid since for area.grid, you would have to define a unique rectangular grid for all animals (which could increase compute time).